# Not able to insert element within another using appendTo

Tags: jquery, append

My jQuery Code is not working and I can't figure out why.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.page-contact-us section#section_2 div.c-rich-text__section').appendTo('.page-contact-us section#section_1 div#map-canvas-prim');
});
```

It selects a div element (that is brought over from another site using ajax) and is supposed to insert content from section 2 into the div element. But it doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Hello, Nathan! There aren't enough details here to give you much help. Can you include any HTML? Maybe make a [mcve]? It may be tricky because this involves AJAX, but we need more details in order to help you.

Comment: If the element is loaded using AJAX, you need to do this in the AJAX success function, since AJAX is asynchronous.